# HTML5 Canvas | Pattern to reveal overlayed line art based on pattern pixel color

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to apply, via canvas element, a one color (black) bitmap image (line art) onto a 2 color (red and yellow) bitmap image (pattern) and have only the red pixels of that pattern be colored by the overlayed line art, kinda like an intersect. I saw this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing (see globalCompositeOperation > Darker method ) and wondered if that effect is what I need. Since that method no longer appears to be supported, is there a way to simulate such an effect? All images used for this only contain spot colors (100% red, 100% yellow, 100% black, 100% white). Any javascript code sample or hint(s) leading to a solution would be awesome. Thx for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can isolate just the red portion onto a separate image then you can use compositing to recolor where black intersects red.

Otherwise you can grab all the pixel colors on both images using `context.getImageData`.

Then you can change the red pixels to black where red & black intersect.

[image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pcsmbr22/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; margin:20px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasB=document.getElementById("black");
    var ctxB=canvasB.getContext("2d");
    var canvasC=document.getElementById("color2");
    var ctxC=canvasC.getContext("2d");

    ctxB.fillRect(50,50,50,100);
    ctxC.fillStyle='yellow';
    ctxC.fillRect(75,50,50,50);
    ctxC.fillStyle='red';
    ctxC.fillRect(75,100,50,50);

    var iDataB=ctxB.getImageData(0,0,canvasB.width,canvasB.height);
    var dataB=iDataB.data;
    var iDataC=ctxC.getImageData(0,0,canvasC.width,canvasC.height);
    var dataC=iDataC.data;

    // copy yellow-red onto results canvas
    ctx.drawImage(canvasC,0,0);

    var iData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    var data=iData.data;

    // copy black pixels when intersecting red pixels
    for(var i=0;i<dataC.length;i+=4){
        var isBlack=(dataB[i]==0 && dataB[i+1]==0 && dataB[i+2]==0 && dataB[i+3]==255);
        var isRed=(dataC[i]==255 && dataC[i+1]==0 && dataC[i+2]==0 && dataC[i+3]==255);
        if(isBlack && isRed){
            data[i]=0;
            data[i+1]=0;
            data[i+2]=0;
            data[i+3]=255;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(iData,0,0);

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="black" width=200 height=200></canvas>
    <canvas id="color2" width=200 height=200></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice! I also found some code that produces a similar ideal which applies to pixels that contain shades of colors:http://jsfiddle.net/26N7S/3/